# Complex Analysis Conformal Mapping/Linear Fractional Transformation.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

everyone.

I am really struggling on this question.  The question is #3 given below.  I am trying to teach the concepts to myself and I am having a tough time with this question.  I found a general formula of a linear fractional transformation that maps a circle to the upper half plane.  When I plug in the center and radius of the circle into the formula, I get the right answer that is given in the back of the book.  However, I don't want to just memorize or plug into a formula because then I don't really understand what I am doing.  There must be a way to find the linear fractional transformation that maps the circle to the upper half plane  another or more explicit way.  Any thoughts, suggestions would be very helpful.  Thank you.  I have attached the question and the formula which I mentioned.

[image]

General Formula found in different textbook:
[image]

Comment: Learn about cross ratio.

Comment: Actually, I just searched up cross ratio, I know what it is, I just don't know how to use it in this case.

Comment: That is my question, how do I use the cross ratio in this case.  I don't understand what 3 points to map to what 3 points.

Comment: Take three points (going around counterclockwise) on the edge of the circle to three points (going left to right) on the edge of the upper half plane. Pick reasonably convenient numbers to work with.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me an example of 3 points to choose for the circle.  Does 2+i, 3i, and -2+i work?

Comment: You want points on the unit circle? How about $1$, $i$, $-1$?

Comment: The Domain is not the unit circle, it is a different circle centered at i with radius 2.

Comment: Oh, then perfect!